# Invalid RGBA argument: masked_array(data=[1.0, 0.5651961183210134, 0.0, 1.0], mask=False, when using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 4d graph using x,y,z labels with the fourth dimension being color. However, when trying to run this code, I run into this:

> Invalid RGBA argument: masked_array(data=[1.0, 0.5651961183210134,
>   0.0, 1.0],
>                mask=False,

only whenever I try to change the z variable. The only time I don't get an error is when I set the z variable to this: `np.random.standard_normal(100)`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = rainfall
y = airport_train_adult_pax
z = airport_total_pax
c = exchange_rate

img = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, cmap=plt.hot())
fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

Just for some background of my data, the rainfall ranges from 0 to 200 and includes one decimal point, airport train and airport total ranges 2000000-3000000 range with no decimals, and exchange_rate ranges between 0 to 1 with two decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have NaNs in your data.

Try to insert this code before ax.scatter(...):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'c': c}).dropna()
x,y,z,c = [df[c] for c in df]
```